# How to add test-jar and jar as dependency in a maven multimodule project?

Tags: java, maven

I have a maven multimodule project of the form

- main

  - query
  - ...
  - storage

    - storage-config
    - storage-utils
    - storage-common
  - tools

I have a class `com.vnera.storage.config.ElasticsearchEmbedded.java` residing under test folder in `storage-config` which I want to use in `storage-utils` from a class `TestStorageUtils` under `test` scope. `storage-utils` also needs `storage-config` in main phase.

In query module I have added dependency of `storage-utils` `test-jar`. But whenever I am trying to access `TestStorageUtils` in from a test in `query` module. It is throwing me the below error. All compilation is running fine.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/van/storage/config/ElasticsearchEmbedded

    at com.van.storage.utils.TestStorageUtils.setUp(TestStorageUtils.java:92)
    at com.van.query.SearchUtilsTests.setUp(SearchUtilsTests.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.van.storage.config.ElasticsearchEmbedded
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 17 more
```

The necessary pom is placed below:-

- [query/pom.xml](https://gist.github.com/debraj-manna/e06728101d2ab59abf0993649d228323)
- [storage/pom.xml](https://gist.github.com/debraj-manna/7c7968e8fb2964ef1421d6a101c727b4)
- [storage/config/pom.xml](https://gist.github.com/debraj-manna/b82abe8fae4b9de6fbb468e328162281)
- [storage/utils/pom.xml](https://gist.github.com/debraj-manna/109f57b682f08b7e3ab0f3264b6209d4)

Can someone let me know what is going wrong and how can I solve this?

Maven Version - 3.5.3

Comment: Can you upload complete versions of all your pom files? Meanwhile, I see you have included your jar twice. One without test scope and one with test scope. Can you remove the one which is not required  and give it a try.

Comment: I need a few of the test classes of `storage-config` in the `test` phase of `storage-utils`. So I have added `test-jar` of `storage-config` also as a dependency in `storage-utils`.

Comment: I have updated the question and added the `pom`s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`query` module also need to declare the test-jar dependency of `storage-config`.

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>com.van</groupId>
            <artifactId>storage-config</artifactId>
            <version>${main.version}</version>
            <classifier>tests</classifier>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <type>test-jar</type>
        </dependency>
```